# Sim.js first program: nothing drawn on the screen

Tags: javascript, three.js, sim.js

I'm following the book "WebGL: up and running". The first program it makes with Sim.js is a bit complicated, and it's hard for me to recognize what every instruction does, and I've not found any reliable Sim.js documentation; So I am trying to write a simpler program just to understand how it works.

This program is "inspired" from the code in the 3rd chapter, which comprises these two files:

1. [earth-basic.js](https://github.com/tparisi/WebGLBook/blob/master/Chapter%203/earth-basic.js);
2. [graphics-earth-basic.html](https://github.com/tparisi/WebGLBook/blob/master/Chapter%203/graphics-earth-basic.html).

I tried to write a program which is essentially the same, but constructing a simple sphere without texture. But probably there's something wrong, because nothing is drawn on the screen: I see a blank page with just the title. This is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Sim.js Test </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 align="center"> Sim.js Test </h1>
        <div id="container" width="400" height="400"> </div>
        <script src="../Three.js-master/build/three.min.js"></script>
        <script src= "../Sim.js-master/sim.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.mousewheel.min.js"> </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            SphereApp= function() {
                Sim.App.call(this);
            }

            SphereApp.prototype= new Sim.App();

            SphereApp.prototype.init= function(param) {
                Sim.App.prototype.init.call(this,param);
                var sphere= new Sphere();
                sphere.init();
                this.addObject(sphere);
            }

            Sphere= function() {
                Sim.Object.call(this);
            }

            Sphere.prototype= new Sim.Object();

            Sphere.prototype.init = function() {
                var object= new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.SphereGeometry(1,10,10), new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color:0xff0000}));
                this.setObject3D(object);
            }

            Sphere.prototype.update= function() {
            }

            $(document).ready( function() {
                var container= document.getElementById("container");
                var app= new SphereApp();
                app.init({container:container});
                app.run(); 
            });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you checked for errors in the browser console? Have you tried using it to debug the code, or adding `console.log()` messages to verify that your code is running?

Comment: No console errors, and I tried to add an alert function before $(document).ready, the alert panel is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding some properties to the HTML `div` element:

```
<div id="container" style="width:100%;height:100%;background-color:black;overflow:hidden; position:absolute;"> </div>
```

The drawing was ok, but the container was hidden.